# Ускорение функции по вычислению коинтеграции двух временных рядов Dickey-Fuller test

Tags: r

Есть функция  по вычислению коинтеграции

```
cointegration <- function(x,y){
  library(tseries)
  vals<-data.frame(x,y)
  beta<-coef(lm(vals[,2]~vals[,1]+0,data=vals))[1]
  (adf.test(vals[,2]-beta*vals[,1], alternative="stationary", k=0))$p.value
}
```

взята от сюда [введите сюда описание ссылки](https://www.r-bloggers.com/time-series-cointegration-in-r/)

Все замечательно, но есть два но

1) Иногда вылетает непонятный мне "варнинг"

```
47: In adf.test(vals[, 2] - beta * vals[, 1], alternative = "stationary",  ... :
  p-value smaller than printed p-value
48: In adf.test(vals[, 2] - beta * vals[, 1], alternative = "stationary",  ... :
  p-value smaller than printed p-value
49: In adf.test(vals[, 2] - beta * vals[, 1], alternative = "stationary",  ... :
  p-value smaller than printed p-value
50: In adf.test(vals[, 2] - beta * vals[, 1], alternative = "stationary",  ... :
  p-value smaller than printed p-value
```

2) Ну и второй самый главный вопрос: Как можно ускорить расчет функции
Мне нужно сравнить около 1 млн рядов, расчет всего лишь 30к рядов уже занимает несколько минут 
Как можно ускорить расчеты на порядки?